# Cannot install libgles2-mesa-dev

Tags: apt, 12.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

When I try this following commands on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-raring
```

I get the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-raring : Depends: libgles2-mesa-lts-raring 
(= 9.1.7-1ubuntu2~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried `sudo apt-get -f install` commands as well it did not work either,

I followed [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) but still I could not get it fixed. Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

Try this following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
```

Hopefully this work for you

Comment: Not worked for me (((